# How to ask for user input a limited number of times in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am trying to write a program that takes numerical input choices from the user (from 1 to 13, so it should only ask for an input up to 13 times) which will then be used to check a CSV file for matching locations. However, I am not sure how to go about this. Currently I have this:

```
            Start: 
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter some Location IDs: ");
            int itemID = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            if (itemID <= 13)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter another ID: ");

            }
            else if (itemID > 13)

            {
                Console.WriteLine("There are only 13 locations available.");
                goto Start;
            }
            if (itemID == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sorry, there is no Location 0.");

            }
```

I am using a label to return to the beginning of the loop. Is this a bad idea? Any help would be appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Also, use `int.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`. With `TryParse` you can handle incorrect inputs easier -- you won't need to catch exceptions.

Comment: Seemingly- this will only `goto Start` when the user inputs an `id` greater than 13. What if they put in something less than 13? It only asks to enter another `id`, but doesn't do allow for the input

Comment: Probably you have not yet read about loops. I suggest to continue your C# studies and rethink about this problem when you understand the different loop statements available

Comment: Thanks, Max. Will do.

Comment: Your question and your code conflict.  You say you should only ask for an input up to 13 TIMES, but your code indicates you want to allow input only up to the VALUE 13 (and ask indefinitely until they get it right).     I think the word "times" in "13 times" should be removed.

Comment: Please don't add tags not specifically related to the question you're asking. This question is unrelated to the actual handling of CSV data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am using a label to return to the beginning of the loop. Is this a bad idea?

Yes. Today would be a great day to learn about `while`.  Two ways to think about `while`:

(1) You know what `if` does.  `if(condition) statement` evaluates `condition`, and if it is true, executes `statement` *once*.

`while` does almost the same thing. `while(condition) statement` evaluates `condition`, and if it is true, executes `statement`, and then checks `condition` again, ... and so on until `condition` is false.

(2) If you understand goto, you can express `while` in terms of `goto`.  `while(condition) statement` is the same as:

```
Continue: if (!condition) goto Break;
statement
goto Continue;
Break:;
```

If you can program with `goto`, you can program the same thing *more clearly* with `while`.

In your particular case though, you likely want to use a `do` loop, which is an upside-down `while`:

```
do statement while(condition);
```

has the behavior of "do the statement, then check the condition; if true, do the statement again... until the condition is false.  `do` has the semantics:

```
Restart: statement
Continue: if (condition) goto Restart;
Break:;
```